# Ubuntu 22.10 bluetooth does not detect devices with bluetooth5.0 or higher

Tags: bluetooth, 22.10

My ubuntu 22.10 distro detects all bluetooth devices except the ones which have bluetooth5.0 or above.

I have tried modprobe, restarting the drivers as well as blueman and bluez but none of them help.

My laptop physical drivers do support bluetooth5.0 devices as I can connect to the same devices on windows (I have dual-booted) but they do not show up in ubuntu settings nor in blueman.

PS : It is not an audio issue, since my bluetooth speaker with bluetoth4.0 is working

Comment: Can you try with an Ubuntu 23.10 live ISO and test if the problem is present there too?

Comment: Yeah it is working in live ISO.

I guess I'll just reinstall it

Comment: In my previous comment, I misspelled the latest version (wrongly) as 23.10. It should be 23.04. And please note that 22.10 will be EOL in less than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

I just booted into a live ISO image of the same distro where I connected it to the mouse (which previously wasn't connecting).

Booted back to the faulty distro and it started working and showing all the devices.